# Como debe ser el formato del modal "Confirm" utilizado en formato JSON usando PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json

Tengo un problema que me tiene desesperado.
Estoy tratando de devolver datos a un "DataTable" en formato JSON, yo habilito 2 botones de acción y estoy tratando de incluir en el botón de eliminar el modal "Confirm" pero solo consigo errores.  Agradezco el apoyo.

Si el formato fuera HTML el botón sería:

Mi código:

```
if ($_POST['action_type'] == 'view') {

    $sql = "SELECT usr_usuario_id, usr_nombre, usr_numero_empleado, usr_correo";
    $sql .= " FROM usuario WHERE usr_empresa_id = ? ";
    $param[] = 'i';
    $param[] = $_POST['empresa_id'];
    $users = execSQL($sql, $param, false);

    $i = 0;
    $tabla = "";
    if (!empty($users)) {
        foreach ($users as $row) {
            $editar = '<a href=\"javascript:void(0);\" class=\"btn btn-primary\" id=\"' . $row['usr_usuario_id'] . '\" data-type=\"edit\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#modalUserAddEdit\"><i class=\"far fa-edit\"></i></a>';

            $eliminar = '<a href=\"javascript:void(0);\" class="btn btn-danger\" onclick=\"return confirm(\"Are you sure to delete data?\")?userAction(\"'delete\"', \"'.$row['id'].'\"):false;\"><i class=\"far fa-trash-alt\"></i></a>';

            $accion = $editar . $eliminar;
            $tabla .= '{"usr_usuario_id":"' . $row['usr_usuario_id'] . '","usr_nombre":"' . $row['usr_nombre'] . '","usr_numero_empleado":"' . $row['usr_numero_empleado'] . '","usr_correo":"' . $row['usr_correo'] . '","accion":"' . $accion . '"},';
            $i++;
        }
        $tabla = substr($tabla, 0, strlen($tabla) - 1);
        echo '{"data":[' . $tabla . ']}';
    }
}
```

Comment: Que errores te salen?

Comment: Datatables Warning: table id: tb_usuarios invalid - JSON response.  For more information about this error, please see: https://datatables.net/tn/1.

Comment: Si quito el boton de eliminar me muestra el datatable cargado.

Comment: Se repite el error.... no funciona

Comment: En el caso del botón "editar", coloco un "\" antes de " (comillas).  Esto funciona bien.  Pero en el caso de eliminar es mucho mas complicado con el modal

Comment: Intenta asi: `$eliminar = '<a href=\"javascript:void(0);\" class=\"btn btn-danger\" onclick=\"return confirm(\'Are you sure to delete data?\')?userAction(\"delete\", \"'.$row['id'].'\"):false;\"><i class=\"far fa-trash-alt\"></i></a>';`

Comment: Hola,  alguien tendrá una solución a mi problema... agradezco sus comentarios